# Make mpv go fullscreen for video files, small window for audio files?

Tags: mpv

I have a bunch of flags I want activated for audio files, another bunch for video files, one of which is the fullscreen flag.
Am I supposed to copy paste those flags into every possible auto profile like this:

```
[extension.mkv]
flag1=
flag2=
...
[extension.mp4]
flag1=
flag2=
...
[extension.mov]
flag1=
flag2=
...
[extension.mp3]
flag3=
flag4=
...
```

Or is there a more optimal way to do this? Maybe somehow define target extensions on one line and then list flags once?